# Newspaper 0.0.6 for web scraping in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I used Python Newspaper lib to develop a web scraping script. I needed to extract the following - URL, Title, Summary, Author and date of publication. I got all except the date of publication. My question is, has anyone used the Newspaper lib to capture publication date?

```
hn.write("***********Article no" + str(x+1) + "************\r\n");
hn.write("URL: "+ article.url+ "\r\n");
hn.write("Title: "+ article.title + "\r\n");
hn.write( "Authors: "+' '.join(map(str, article.authors)));
hn.write("\r\n");
hn.write("Summary: "+ article.summary+ "\r\n);
hn.write("Key words: ");
hn.write(str(article.keywords).strip('[]'));
```

Is there a way to get the date of publication using Newspaper lib?

Thanks

Mukesh

Answer (score 3):

There is line 195 in `newspaper/article.py`

```
# TODO self.publish_date = self.config.publishDateExtractor.extract(self.doc)
```

It seems it is not ready yet. But you can try to uncomment this code.

Source: https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/master/newspaper/article.py#L195

Comment: Furas,  Thanks... I uncommented the line and executed the script. It gives me parse error! I guess I have to wait for this functionality to get implemented.